# Add first column if all other columns are the same (AWK)

Tags: awk

I have a file with the following data:

```
25  POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
25  POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
3   PostScript document text conforming DSC level 3.0, type EPS, Level 2
2   PostScript document text conforming DSC level 3.0, type EPS, Level 2
23  PostScript document text conforming DSC level 3.0, type EPS, Level 2
4   SVG Scalable Vector Graphics image
4   SVG Scalable Vector Graphics image
```

and would like to sum first field if all other fields are the same, so the output should be:

```
50  POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
28  PostScript document text conforming DSC level 3.0, type EPS, Level 2
8   SVG Scalable Vector Graphics image
```

I tried this awk command:

```
awk '{ a[$2]+=$1 }END{ for(i in a) print a[i],i }' inputfile
```

which prints:

```
25 POSIX
28 PostScript
8 SVG
```

but I can't find a way to print the rest of the line

Comment: Is the white space between the number and the first letter blank chars or a tab char?

Comment: those are blank chars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way:

```
$ awk '{v=$1;$1="";s[$0]+=v}END{for(i in s)print s[i] i}' file
8 SVG Scalable Vector Graphics image
50 POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
28 PostScript document text conforming DSC level 3.0, type EPS, Level 2
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '{
    v=$1              # store value in $1
    $1=""             # empty $1, record gets rebuilt
    s[$0]+=v          # sum indexing on $1less record
}
END {                 # in the end
    for(i in s)       # loop all 
        print s[i] i  # ... and output
}' file
```

Comment: `$1=""` will alter the rest of the whitespace on the line, I think. If that could cause a problem, you could instead use something like `sub(/[0-9]+[\t ]+/,"")

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{n=$1; sub(/[0-9]+ +/,""); a[$0]+=n} END{ for(i in a) print a[i],i }' file
28 PostScript document text conforming DSC level 3.0, type EPS, Level 2
50 POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
8 SVG Scalable Vector Graphics image
```

Answer (score 1):

Another awk with 'sort'

```
$  sort -k2 sergio.txt | awk  ' { t=$1; $1=""; c=$0;if(c==p) { s+=b} else { if(NR>1) print s+b,p; s=0} p=c;b=t} END { print s+b,p } ' sergio.txt
50  POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
28  PostScript document text conforming DSC level 3.0, type EPS, Level 2
8  SVG Scalable Vector Graphics image
$
```

Input file:

```
$ cat sergio.txt
25  POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
25  POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
3   PostScript document text conforming DSC level 3.0, type EPS, Level 2
2   PostScript document text conforming DSC level 3.0, type EPS, Level 2
23  PostScript document text conforming DSC level 3.0, type EPS, Level 2
4   SVG Scalable Vector Graphics image
4   SVG Scalable Vector Graphics image
$
```